# Rotating android canvas causes myRect.contains(X,Y) not to work

Tags: android, rotation, android-canvas, touch-event

I've written a custom view that displays text in the center of the screen as seen below.
[image]

I've also made it so that if you touch the green box you can rotate and scale the text as seen below.
[image]

Heres the problem.
Whenever I rotate the text and let go, then try to rotate again it cant detect that the rect is being touched using myRect.contains(X,Y).
After some time I found that after its rotated, and touch where the original green box was, it allows me to rotate again.

OnTouchEvent is obviously calculating the Rects position correctly since it drawing in the correct location. I just can figure out why the touch coordinates seem to be referencing old positions.

Here's my onDraw() method.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate((float)mAngle, mBorderRect.centerX(), mBorderRect.centerY());
    canvas.drawRect(mBorderRect, mTextBorderPaint);
    canvas.drawText(mText, mBorderRect.left, mBorderRect.bottom, mTextPaint);
    canvas.drawRect(mResizeRect, mBGPaint);
    canvas.restore();

}
```

Comment: Hi, can you post example on the solutions? Currently I am having the same issue as yours, but I not very sure on how to inverse rotation on the touch position first.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that you're rotating the canvas, not the Rect. To get this to work you'll have to apply the inverse rotation on the touch position first, then compute myRect.contains(X,Y).

Comment: This is one of those "Duh!" moments for me, Thanks. that worked.

Comment: if you dont mind, can help me on this issue?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801019/rotating-one-of-the-canvas-causes-rect-containsx-y-not-to-work

thanks

Comment: @Ricky I never found a perfect solution for my issue. I asked another question (link below). In the comments a guy suggested something that didn't work for me because i was doing something very specific, but it could work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689111/finding-a-point-after-android-canvas-rotation#comment36406211_23689111

Comment: Hey Kent, ok, noted on that. I will look through it. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @KentAndersen and anakin78Z  I have tried inverse the rotation on touch position.but it did not work well.I have tried something like this.create a new matrix and post rotate the matrix.and invert the matrix .Can u help me with this..