# Finding a point after android canvas rotation

Tags: android, rotation, android-canvas

**Background info:**

Using the android canvas and the onDraw() method, I draw a Rect with a small bitmap.
Using onTouchEvent() I calculate a rotation on the canvas and do the following.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.rotate((float)mAngle, mBorderRect.centerX(), mBorderRect.centerY());
        canvas.drawBitmap(mCloseBitmap, null, mCloseRect, null);    
}
```

After the canvas is rotated, the Rect still has the same left, top, right, bottom coordinates.
So, when I touch the screen it doesn't register that the rect has been touched.

**Question:**

If I know the angle of rotation and the original XY coordinates, how do I calculate the new XY coordinates after the rotation has occurred?
(Math isn't my strong suit)

Comment: draw the Bitmap using the Matrix, then use Matrix.mapPoints

Comment: That works for the bitmap only. When the bitmap rotates around a center point, everything else on the canvas needs to do the same.

Comment: so use Canvas.concat(Matrix) before any Canvas.draw* methods and use Canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, paint)

Comment: @KentAndersen how did you end up solving this issue? I am rotating a canvas now to rotate text but then the text isn't drawn at the touched location anymore.